# highcharts custom colors and tootip point color

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, colors, highcharts

I add custom colors stops with gradients but tooltips point colors are objetcs, no rgb, and no show base color in pointFormat. The legend show base colors, no have problem with labels.

```
pointFormat : '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span>'+
' {series.name} {series.color} - {point.color}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>' }
```

**Customs Colors Chart**
[image: Custom Colors]

**Default Colors Chart**
[image: Default Colors]

Here my sample http://jsfiddle.net/castocolina/2mdt9rhb/
Try to comment and uncomment the custom colors block

How fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens for 2 reasons:

1. The new custom color is not a solid color, but rather a gradient, therefore when you try to extract the "series.color" a gradient is obtained, the style="color" value requires a solid color to be shown.
2. According to the documentation on point formatting (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.pointFormat) the coloring seems be done on the "pointFormat" field but I'm not sure why it does not works there... Hopefully it works on the "formatter" field. Maybe a bug on HighCharts?

Here is the new "formatter" field:

```
formatter: function() {
    var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';

    $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
    s += '<br/><span style="color:'+ point.series.color.stops[1][1] +'">\u25CF</span>: ' + point.series.name + ': ' + point.y;
    });

    return s;
}
```

Here is a the working demo with the colors: https://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/pL0yzfsx/3/

Note that the point can't be formatted with a gradient therefore I have chosen the highlighted part of the color which corresponds to "point.series.color.stops[1][1]"

Comment: Thanks @adelriosantiago, this is good solution, but produce error with the Pie mouseover event, maybe the tooltip process.

In Chrome:
_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined_ jquery-1.9.1.js:622

In ff
_TypeError: obj is undefined_ jquery-1.9.1.js:622:3

Trace the error and is produce by highcharts. 
I try with others versions of jQuery and problem persist. Try enable tooltip for pie and no success. I think to enable labels over plot.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot @adelriosantiago, I added a condition to check points or point property depends of series or pie. The latest version of highcharts (4.1.5) have problem to display tooltip of embedded pie, I had to use a previous version (4.0.4)

```
formatter : function() {
    var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
    var color = null;

    if (typeof this.points != 'undefined') {
        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
            color = point.series.color.stops[1][1];
            if (i == 3) {
                s += '<br/><span style="color:' + color + '">\u00A2</span> ';
                s += point.series.name + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 2);
            } else {
                s += '<br/><span style="color:' + color + '">\u25CF</span> ';
                s += point.series.name + ': ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 0);
            }
        });
    } else {
        color = this.point.color.stops[1][1];
        s = '<h3 style="color:' + color + '; font-weight: bold;">' + this.point.name + '</h3>';
        s += '<br/><span style="color:' + color + '">\u25CF</span> ';
        s += Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 2) + ' (' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.percentage, 2) + '%)';
    }

    return s;
}
```

Here the full fix http://jsfiddle.net/castocolina/2mdt9rhb/4/